# Can I get my AE2 network to see what's in my logistic pipes network?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-mods

I have a big Logistics Pipes (LP) network setup, and I'm moving over to an AE2 network, and I want to connect them together. I found [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3tOBlBkMSpM), and it half works. Through the request pipe I'm able to see whats in my AE network, but not the other way around.

I notice that tutorial is using AE1, so I'm guessing that's my problem. Does anyone know what else I could get this working?

Here's a simplified example of what I have.

[image]

So I can request from the AE using the request pipe, but I cant see what's in the chest through my AE interface.

I'm using the FTB Infinity pack, and minecraft version 1.7.10.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong.  AE2 currently doesn't support Request Logistics Pipe integration.  See [Issue 21](https://github.com/AppliedEnergistics/Applied-Energistics-2/issues/21)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... You cant really read of of the Logistics Network with AE2 to see what items it has but you could use storage buses on chests! Other than that im not sure if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

Just get as many drives as possible then import all of you things into the AE network, then replace all your logistics network with AE, most of the things you can do with most of your logistics system can be done with a good AE one. That is what I recommend.